# Jooq replace function

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I see a strange behavior when i use JOOQ to generate my original SQL.

```
    CAST(addi.addke AS VARCHAR(10))||CAST(tlcst.tdsk AS
            VARCHAR(10))||date_format(DATE (rol.ntbd), '%Y%m%d')||replace(adft.ati,':','')  SPOT_ID,
```

I created a JOOQ script for the above SQL as

```
concat((field("addi.addke").cast(SQLDataType.VARCHAR(10))),
                    (field("tlcst.tdsk").cast(SQLDataType.VARCHAR(10))),
                    (dateFormat(field("rol.ntbd"), "%Y%m%d")),
                    (replace(field("adft.ati", String.class), ":", ""))).as(field("SPOT_ID")))
```

And it generates as below SQL which is having `?` symbol on replace function.

```
(
cast(addi.addke as varchar(10)) || cast(tlcst.tdsk as varchar(10)) || date_format(rol.ntbd, '%Y%m%d') || replace(adft.ati, ?, ?)) as "SPOT_ID"
```

How can i not get those `?` marks in replace function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above issue with replace function by

```
concat((field("addi.arr").cast(SQLDataType.VARCHAR(10))),
                    (field("tlcst.tee").cast(SQLDataType.VARCHAR(10))),
                    (dateFormat(date("rol.hhh"), "%Y%m%d")),
                    (replace(field("adft.jjj", String.class), field("':'", String.class), field("''", String.class)))).as(field("SPOT_ID")))
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, jOOQ wraps all of your variables as bind variables, which is akin to calling [`DSL.val()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#val-T-) behind the scenes. You want to inline those values in your particular case, so you have to use [`DSL.inline()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#inline-T-) instead. So, make a call to:

```
replace(field("adft.ati", String.class), inline(":"), inline(""))
```

[For more details about bind values, please refer to the manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/).